# Can I authorize a public Slack App without an add to slack button?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm looking to create a public slack app, the app will initially post webhooks from a third party into a channel and will also have a single command, given it'll be public I know I need to authorise slack permissions, is it possible to set a redirect url within the app settings without having to create a landing page with an add to slack button.

Having looked through the slack settings there is a redirect url option within the oauth settings of app configuration though when I install an app to my workspace and accept permissions it does not use this redirect url so I'm assuming this is only used in conjunction with an add to slack button.

Thoughts would be appreciated. This has stumped me for a number of days, the documentation seems to either lean towards using the tokens within the settings which would work within a private app or to use an add to slack button, I'm a backend golang dev who is looking to avoid any frontend dev work if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want your app to be public without having a landing page with a button? If you want your app to be published and searchable on the Slack App directory then having a landing page is the only option. If you don't want it published you app can still be public by simply using the shareable url that gets configured on your `Manage Distribution` section. You'll have to provide this url to those who want to install your app and they will get automatically redirected to the authentication page.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I do want it to be public so I'll go with your suggestion of creating a landing page.